# Error: insert enum identifier and enum body

Tags: java, enums

Here is my code both syntax errors are on line 16 more specifically  "private getTotalGrains(k, grains);" from reading other similar questions it might have something to do with writing a method inside another method? If I am i'm not experienced enough to see it help would be amazing.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Grain
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 {  
  Grain grain = new Grain();
  grain.getTotalGrains();
 }
  int grains = 0;
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("How many days shall the program run for? Please enter a number between 1 and 64.");
  int k = keyboard.nextInt();

 private getTotalGrains(k, grains);
  {
     k = k-1;
     grains = grains * 2;

    do
    {
       getTotalGrains(k, grains);
    }
    while(k == 1);
    {
      System.out.println(grains + " grains of rice.");
    }
    while(k < 1);
    {
      System.out.println("Invalid number please try again.");
    }
    while(k > 64);
    {
      System.out.println("Invalid number please try again.");
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: You totally confused the compiler by placing a method (getTotalGrains) into another method, which is not allowed in Java. Additionally, the method's declaration line (again getTotalGrains) contains a semicolon where it does not belong. Sticking to Java code conventions would have revealed both.

Comment: You're right: You can't nest methods. In this case, they need to be side-by-side at the same level in the class.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is nothing about enums here.

You code contains multiple syntax mistakes. Take a look on the following fragment.

```
private getTotalGrains(k, grains);
  {
```

1. return type is missing
2. parameter types are missing.
3. There is redundant `;` after the method definition.

This should be re-written as:

```
private void getTotalGrains(int k, int grains) {
```

Moreover you try to define method `getTotalGrains` inside method `main` that is not supported by java.

I guess that there are other mistakes as well.